# Hyperledger fabric creation with AWS Blockchain template. error The following resource(s) failed to create: [EC2InstanceForDev]

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric

I am creating a Blockchain network using the AWS hyperledger fabric template. 
The policy:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Here is the error:

```
Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:506678340351:stack/blockchainbook-FabricEC2CommonStack-8DF2HAE5AFA4/5f2804b0-4669-11ea-b41c-0ac97ebd7097 was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [EC2InstanceForDev].
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide link to the template?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blockchain/templates/getting-started/ . i am using AWS blockchain template for hyperledger fabric